# Saving array of data to database using wordpress settings API

Tags: wordpress

There.
I am currently developing a wp plugins and having problems of how to save array of data using its settings API.

I know i can do this

```
<select name = my_plugin_options[mode]>
```

but how can I do when my_plugin_options[mode] = array('high','low')?Can I do like below? And I try it but it seems doesn't work.Anyone could advise me would be appreciated.

```
<select name = my_plugin_options[mode][high]>
```

Comment: Hello jun, your question is unclear, can you please explain in other form with examples?

Comment: Hi,@josedasilva.You know with wp settings api we can create a menu page displayed in admin panel.There can be a bunch of settings areas inside a large form section,such as text,textarea,select and in the end there is a submit  button.After it has been clicked the settings value would pass into wp database through the name attribute which is like `<select name = my_plugin_options[id]>`.But if the id itself is a array how can I do with it?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to make some mistakes before and actually this can work well. 
  `<select name = my_plugin_options[mode][high]>`
It can input value into database from the select name attribute as

```
my_plugin_options => array(
   'mode'=>array(
       'hight => 'value',
       'low'  => 'value
       ),
   'stuff'=> ...
)
```